# How to find the positive region of this function?

Tags: equation-solving, finance

I'm new-ish to Mathematica and I'm using it to learn the basics of derivative trading (for fun not for trading!). I've defined a simple function to calculate the pay off of a trading on a call. I have no problem drawing the P/(L) diagram but I cannot find which Mathematica function to use to get the region of x for which my P/(L) is positive. Can you help?

---

My function is basic and calculates the difference  between the cost of the call (callPremium) and value of the Call at expiration:

```
 PayOffCall[currentPrice_?NumberQ, strikePrice_?NumberQ, 
   callPremium_?NumberQ] := 
  FinancialDerivative[{"European", 
     "Call"}, {"StrikePrice" -> strikePrice, 
     "Expiration" -> 0}, {"InterestRate" -> 0.1, "Volatility" -> 0.2, 
     "CurrentPrice" -> currentPrice, "Dividend" -> 0.05}] - 
   callPremium;
```

I can then easily plot the P/(L) diagram

```
ListLinePlot[{#, PayOffCall[#, 50, 2]} & /@ Range[47, 57, 1], 
 AxesLabel -> {"Strike Price at Expiration", "P/(L)"}]
```

[image]

I can find the break-even point:

```
In:= FindRoot[PayOffCall[x, 50, 2] == 0, {x, 47, 57}] // Quiet
Out:= {x -> 52.}
```

And now I'd like Mathematica to tell me that *PayOffCall[x,50,2] is positive for x>=52*.

I've tried different function without any success: Solve,NSolve, FindMaximum, etc... but I think my Mathematica skills are letting me down.

For instance:

```
In:= NSolve[PayOffCall[x, 50, 2] > 0, x]
NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve. >>
Out:= NSolve[PayOffCall[x, 50, 2] > 0, x]
```

I'd like to know the right function to return:

```
Out:= {x>52.}
```

Any help to this newbie question is much appreciated!

---

Thanks to [b.gatessucks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/134/b-gatessucks) for his answer. Now if I define an additional function for Put

```
PayOffPut[currentPrice_?NumberQ, strikePrice_?NumberQ, 
   putPremium_?NumberQ] := 
  FinancialDerivative[{"European", 
     "Put"}, {"StrikePrice" -> strikePrice, 
     "Expiration" -> 0}, {"InterestRate" -> 0.1, "Volatility" -> 0.2, 
     "CurrentPrice" -> currentPrice, "Dividend" -> 0.05}] - 
   putPremium;
```

I can draw the P/L diagram for a "Long Straddle" where I buy a 50 Call at 3 USD and I buy 50 Put at 2 USD

```
ListLinePlot[{#, PayOffCall[#, 50, 3] + PayOffPut[#, 50, 2]} & /@ 
  Range[41, 59, 1], 
 AxesLabel -> {"Strike Price at Expiration", "P/(L)"}]
```

[image]

But then neither FindRoot or NMinimize return the correct region

```
In:= FindRoot[PayOffCall[x, 50, 3] + PayOffPut[x, 50, 2] == 0, {x, 47, 57}]
Out:= {x -> 55.}
In:= NMinimize[{x, 41 < x < 60, 
  PayOffCall[x, 50, 3] + PayOffPut[x, 50, 2] > 0}, x]
Out:= {41., {x -> 41.}}
```

What's the solution then!?

---

**Update**
Thanks to eldo and  b.gatessucks answers, I created the following simple algorithm:

```
<< RootSearch`
f[x_] := PayOffCall[x, 50, 3] + PayOffPut[x, 50, 2];
r = RootSearch[f[x] == 0, {x, 1, 100}]; // Quiet
r2 = x /. r; AppendTo[r2, r2[[-1]]*1.5]; PrependTo[r2, 0.0001];
r2 = Partition[r2, 2, 1]
Do[
  v = f[#] & /@ Range[##, 1.] & @@ r2[[n]];
  AppendTo[r2[[n]], "Profit" -> AllTrue[v, # >= 0 &]],
  {n, Length[r2]}];
r2
```

Which returns what I needed:

```
{{0.0001, 45., "Profit" -> True}, {45., 55., "Profit" -> False}, {55.,
   82.5, "Profit" -> True}}
```

Comment: You can do `NMinimize[{x , 0 < x < 100, PayOffCall[x, 50., 2.] > 0}, x]`.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much. I wouldn't have thought of this one.

Comment: This is not a discussion forum.  We follow a Question & Answer format instead.  Therefore it is appropriate to put extensions and clarifications to your original question in the Question itself (by editing it).  I have moved your content for you in this case.

Comment: You can use the package [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4482/) with `RootSearch[
 PayOffCall[x, 50, 3] + PayOffPut[x, 50, 2] == 0, {x, 0, 100}]` to find all the zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

**PayOffCall**

Select a limit large enough for your purposes:

```
lim = 100.;
```

Compute the values:

```
v1 = {#, PayOffCall[#, 50, 2]} & /@ Range[lim];
```

Create an interpolating function:

```
f = Interpolation[v1, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Plot[f[x], {x, 1, lim}]
```

[image]

We can evaluate `f` for arbitrary points

```
{f[1.4], f[61.3]}
```

> {-2., 9.3}

Find the break-even point

```
break = FindInstance[f[x] == 0, x, Reals][[1, 1, 2]]
```

> 52.

Is `PayOffCall` positive for `x >= 52`?

```
v2 = f[#] & /@ Range[break, lim, 1.];

AllTrue[v2, NonNegative] (* Version 10 *)
```

> True

```
And @@ (NonNegative /@ v2) (* Prior versions *)
```

**Call + Put**

```
v1 = (PayOffCall[#, 50, 3] + PayOffPut[#, 50, 2]) & /@ Range[lim];

f = Interpolation[v1, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

roots = Rest @ NestList[FindInstance[f[x] == 0 && x > #, x, Reals][[1, 1, 2]] &, 0., 2]
```

> {45., 55.}

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 41, 59},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[y >= 0, Green, Red]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 AxesOrigin -> {41, 0},
 Ticks -> {roots, Automatic},
 ImageSize -> 500,
 AxesLabel -> {"Strike Price at Expiration", "P/(L)"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing answer. Thanks eldo. I will try this immediately.